# Tuleap - Active Directory - Users Suspended automatically

Tags: active-directory, ldap, tuleap

```
i have integrated Tuleap with active directory, i can able to add the users with the project.The Problem is that the users are getting suspended automatically for every 24 hrs.
```

So i am stuck with this problem. I have spent hours reading and trying to sort this out. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? here is my 
ldap.inc

```
<?php
$sys_ldap_server = '10.10.100.10';
$sys_ldap_dn   = 'DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=com';
$sys_ldap_bind_dn = "Ldapquery@xxx.xxx-xxx.com";
$sys_ldap_bind_passwd = "xxxxxnnn";
$sys_ldap_uid   = 'sAMAccountname';
$sys_ldap_eduid = 'sAMAccountname';
$sys_ldap_people_dn = 'DC=xxx,DC=xxx-xxx,DC=xxx';
$sys_ldap_search_user='(|(sAMAccountname=%words%)(cn=%words%)(mail=%words%))';
$sys_ldap_tooltip_search_user='(&(|(sn=%words%*) (cn=%words%*)(department=%words%*) 
(givenName=%words%*)(sAMAccountname=%words%*))(!(givenName=BoiteVocale))(sAMAccountname=*))';
$sys_ldap_tooltip_search_attrs='sAMAccountname;sn;givenName;cn;name;displayName;department';
$sys_ldap_default_user_status = 'A';
$sys_ldap_svn_auth = 0;
$sys_ldap_daily_sync = 1;
$sys_ldap_user_management = 1;
$sys_ldap_grp_enabled   = 0;
$sys_ldap_grp_dn        = ' ';
$sys_ldap_grp_cn        = ' ';
$sys_ldap_grp_member    = ' ';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the ldap_daily_sync and you should be good :)